# How to make a excel file with laravel excel with beautified or nice looking tables?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-excel

Heres my problem. I want to make a good looking table for my orders and inventory stock as excel files. But I can't find how to import tables in the file and save it and not create another new file.

Please help me on what can I do here!

Laravel Version : 8.1.10

Laravel Excel Version : 3.1

Thanks!

Comment: For styling tables you can use macros https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/extending.html#customize

Comment: You are asking about styling table at first, and then you are asking about how to overwrite existing file, please [take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok that you want show beautified your excel file, if you use untidy code and config it will has lot of load and burden on your php-cgi.

you can use phpspreadsheet for this work
after that you can change cell color with this code:

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2')->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_RED);